# Page goes black on opening jquery mobile panel

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, windows-phone, panel

I am making a hybrid app, in which I have a left panel. On opening the left panel my page turns black. I am facing this problem only in windows phone 8. Panels work properly on android devices. Is there a problem with Windows support for jQuery Mobile?

I have an image for the menu button. onclick event of this image i have called a javascript function. the javascript function is as follows

```
    <img src="images/leftnav_icon.png" id="leftnavImage" onclick="OpenLeftPanel()"/>

function OpenLeftPanel() {

$('#myPanel ul').listview();
$('#myPanel ul').listview('refresh');
$("#myPanel").panel("open");
}
```

Comment: Do you only use default JQM to open/close the panel= If not, do you have some custom code you might want to share?

Comment: ^ I have edited the question. Thank you very much for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help. I got this problem solved. I just added a footer to all my pages and the left panel works fine now! CSS for footer is

```
    #yourFooterId{
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 1px;
     opacity: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just opening the panel th default way like described in the [docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/)

```
 <a href="#[your_panel_id]" data-rel="panel">
   <img src="..." />
 </a>
```

The `data-rel` should be optional. To run your listview-foo, bind to `panelbeforeopen` and run your stuff then (described on the same link as above).

Comment: Didn't work. When I keep position of header and content fixed, the panel pushes the page in android device. But in windows device, the panel renders behind the header and content. z-index for panel is 9 and for content and header is 1 but still panel renders behind header and content. to solve this I changed header and content position to absolute and now the page goes black when panel opens. The divs on the page are still active in windows device and can be clicked when panel has opened.